# SQLAlchemy: Converting Self-Ref JOIN, COUNT, GROUP BY SELECT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have been struggling for a day to get an SQL Select statement that works into the equivalent SQLAlchemy code.  It involves two tables.

A Tags table

```
class Tags(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't_tags'
    uid                 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category            = Column(Enum('service', 'event', 'attribute', name='enum_tag_category'))
    name                = Column(String(32))
```

And a table that maps them to their originating parents

```
class R_Incident_Tags(Base):
    __tablename__ ='r_incident_tags'
    incident_uid        = Column(String(48), ForeignKey('t_incident.uid'), primary_key=True)
    tag_uid             = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('t_tags.uid'), primary_key=True)

    tag = relationship("Tags", backref="r_incident_tags")
```

incident_uid is a unique string to identify the parent.

The SELECT I have been struggling to represent in SQLAlchemy is as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name, e.name, count(e.name)
    FROM "t_tags" AS s,
         "t_tags" AS e,
         "r_incident_tags" AS sr,
         "r_incident_tags" AS er
    WHERE   s.category='service' AND
            e.category='event' AND
            e.uid = er.tag_uid AND
            s.uid = sr.tag_uid AND
            er.incident_uid = sr.incident_uid
    GROUP BY s.name, e.name
```

Any assistance would be appreciated as I haven't even got close to getting something working after a whole day of effort.

Kindest Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
s = aliased(Tags)
e = aliased(Tags)
sr = aliased(R_Incident_Tags)
er = aliased(R_Incident_Tags)

qry = (session.query(s.name, e.name, func.count(e.name)).
        select_from(s, e, sr, er).
        filter(s.category=='service').
        filter(e.category=='event').
        filter(e.uid == er.tag_uid).
        filter(s.uid == sr.tag_uid).
        filter(er.incident_uid == sr.incident_uid).
        group_by(s.name, e.name)
        )
```

But you could also use `relationship`-based `JOIN`s instead of simple `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Thank you so much @van - that worked perfectly - I was clearly over complicating it.